# Devexpress mvc html editor spell check not works

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have MVC project which use DevExpress ASP.NET MVC HTMLEditor. Editor is in partial view, that renders on callback. Here is spell checking init settings:

```
@Html.DevExpress().HtmlEditor(
settings =>
{
    settings.SettingsSpellChecker.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us");
    ASPxSpellCheckerISpellDictionary dictionary = new ASPxSpellCheckerISpellDictionary();
    dictionary.AlphabetPath = "~/Content/Dictionaries/EnglishAlphabet.txt";
    dictionary.GrammarPath = "~/Content/Dictionaries/english.aff";
    dictionary.DictionaryPath = "~/Content/Dictionaries/american.xlg";
    dictionary.CacheKey = "ispellDic";
    dictionary.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us");
    dictionary.EncodingName = "Western European (Windows)";
    settings.SettingsSpellChecker.Dictionaries.Add(dictionary);

    ...

    settings.Toolbars.Add(toolbar =>
        {
            toolbar.Items.Add(new ToolbarCheckSpellingButton(true));

            ...

        }
}).GetHtml()
```

But when I press "Check spelling" button editor does not perform any actions (just send callback to rerender the partial view) and there no errors in js console.

Is there ani additional options to enable spell check which I forgot to check?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add these to your layout after that try.